# Последовательность применения конфигов apache и nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер

Есть LAMP-сервер Ubuntu с панелью VestaCP. В нём в директории home/user/conf/web лежат 2 файла:

```
domain.com.apache2.conf
domain.com.nginx.conf
```

Используются ли оба и в какой последовательности?

Вероятно nginx настроен только на отдачу статики, а через apache работает PHP. Так ли это и как это можно проверить? Хотелось бы детально представлять как идёт запрос и в каком случае и как разруливается каждым из этих конфигов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сервере одновременно могут быть запущены и nginx и apache, но только кто-то один из них может завладеть 80 портом.

Обычно в качестве фронтенда выступает nginx, который слушает 80 и 443 порт по протоколам HTTP и HTTPS.

Часть запросов (статика) обрабатывает сам, а часть прокидывает дальше, на апач.
При этом (поскольку апач уже не может занять 80 порт) апач слушает порт в районе 8000 или 8080, да и вообще слушает их только на 127.0.0.1

И вообще-то обычно не складывают файлы апача и nginx в один каталог, ну да ладно, видать такая панель попалась.

В любом случае, у nginx есть главный конфиг который лежит где-нибудь в /etc/nginx и в котором написано что-то типа include /etc/nginx/conf.d/include *.conf

Аналогично у апача тоже есть главный конфиг, который лежит где-нибудь в /etc/httpd и в котором тоже есть строчка, которая подключает *.conf

Но раз у вас всё лежит в одном каталоге, то создатели панели заменили `include *.conf` на маску: у nginx будет `include domain.com.*.conf` и аналогичное у апача.

Всё вышеописанное не относится к какой-то конкретной панели, это общие сведения по nginx и апач - поэтому вооружившись этими знаниями вы сможете разобраться в устройстве любой панели.